# UITableView cell vertical centering of label when another is empty

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that contains two labels positioned vertically one on top of another, and I am using AutoLayout.
The cell works (and looks) fine when both labels have some text.

Sometimes, though, the top label does not contain any text, and in this case I would the cell to have the same height, but the bottom label to be centered vertically. Is it possible to do it with AutoLayout without modifying the constraints at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this can be accomplished without modifying *something* at run time. I see a few options if you'd like to do this without changing constraints programmatically, some messier than others:

**First option, you could set three labels in the cell**. Two labels that are stacked vertically and one that covers the whole cell vertically, fully overlapping both other labels. At runtime you can determine if the bottom label shouldn't contain text and then set the overlapping top label with the text you would have previously set on the top vertically stacked label.

**Second option, you could utilize a label that has the height of both labels you currently have**. Set this new (2x height) label to allow for 2 lines (can be done in InterfaceBuilder side options). Then at runtime interpolate the label.text attribute with both label's text. Put a new line character in between the labels if the second label has text. It would look something like this

In Swift:

```
my2xLabel.text = "\(firstLabelString) \n \(secondLabelString)"
```

In Obj-C:

```
my2xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", firstLabelString, secondLabelString];
```

All of this being said, modifying the constraints at runtime may be a less hacky way to achieve this formatting.

Comment: Even though it's not exactly the most elegant approach I think that the first option is a valid idea

Answer (score 1):

Make two prototype cells then. One will be the one you have right now, the other would contain only one label but centred vertically. Check if the text would be empty, return the cell with the vertically centred label. Otherwise, return the other cell.

Comment: That was also one of my ideas, but I would prefer a more general approach.

Comment: The problem is you don't want to modify the constraints. If you are using autolayout, and you want to move a subview, what I know is you have to change the constraints. So I don't think this is possible.